# new change id not being generated with .git/hooks

Tags: android, git, gerrit, repository

I am trying to push a change to a remote server and running into "change closed "error,thats because the change-id am
trying to push is same as an earlier change that was already pushed(dont know why its same),I trid to generate a new commit
message using the .git/hook,it generates a new commit-msg but my change-id is still the same and I cant push still,
any inputs on why a new change-id is not being generated?

```
<username:promt>git push ssh://repo.company.com:29418/platform/vendor/com-proprietary/radio HEAD:refs/for/master
Counting objects: 1852, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (688/688), done.
Writing objects: 100% (809/809), 1.37 MiB, done.
Total 809 (delta 678), reused 177 (delta 95)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (678/678)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
To ssh://username@repo.company.com:29418/platform/vendor/com-proprietary/radio
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (change 219386 closed)
error: failed to push some refs to 
'ssh://username@repo.company.com:29418/platform/vendor/com-proprietary/radio'
```

Tried to generate a change id using below

```
cd .git/hooks
scp -p -P 29418 username@repo.company.com:hooks/commit-msg .
cd ../..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you run to generate a change id only copied the commit hook to your repository. Now you shoud do

```
git commit --amend
```

delete the existing change id from the message, and the commit hook will create you a new one. The commit hook uses the following to create the change-id:

- SHA-1 of the tree being committed
- SHA-1 of the parent commit
- Name, email address, timestamp of the author
- Name, email address, timestamp of the committer
- Proposed commit message (before Change-Id was inserted)

If you change any of these, you'll get a different id. Easiest to edit the commit message, of course.

Comment: Thanks,I see new change id being gnenerated now but i still get "(change 219386 closed)" error...219386 is in merged status..do you have any suggestions how to overcome this?

Comment: Would you happen to have accidentally made modifications to a previous commit that was already merged? Double check the sha1 of the previous commits and compare your tree to what the webui says. If you have modified a merged commit you need to cherry-pick the new commit to a fresh topic branch based on the merged tip.

Comment: Is there a way we can push only the commit we want to ,currently am using the command "git push ssh://company.com:29418/platform/code HEAD:refs/for/master",so its probably trying to push all the changes I have in my local tree..i might have made more changes..

Comment: You can fetch the latest merged commit by e.g. `"git fetch ssh://company.com:29418/platform/code master:tip` which creates a new branch tip for you. Then `git checkout tip` and `git cherry-pick <sha1>` where sha1 is the commit you want to push. After these steps you only have this one commit that push tries to put forward.

Answer (score 1):

`! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (change 219386 closed)`

Looks like the change is abandoned (**Restore Change** in *Gerrit WebUI* from your last change and try `push`again) or already submitted/merged(`push` your `commit` as new change).

Comment: thats what I am trying to do,pushing as a new commit but my new commit keeps taking the changed id from 219386

Comment: does anyone else have any ideas?